# WebStorm remove css selectors

Tags: html, webstorm

How can I remove this from my WS? can't find in the documentation...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Appearance`
3. Disable `Show breadcrumbs` sort of options (in case if there are more than one; AFAIK in 2016.2 it's just one .. but in 2016.3 should be separate option per language)